# Portable Java Web Start Cache Location

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm trying to make a java web start application portable. It stores some stuff in the user's home directory, and also a bunch of stuff in the cache. I'm using portableapps.com's portable java, and I've got it to store the home folder stuf using -J-Duser.home="Data", but how do I change the web cache, preferrably to a folder called "cache" in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html).  If you are on Windows you can go to the Java Control Panel and change the cache directory that way.